# Flutter The system cannot find the path specified

Tags: java, android, android-studio, flutter, dart

I am shifting from android studio to flutter. Yesterday, I tried to setup flutter in android studio. I downloaded the zip folder flutter_window_1.22.5-stable.zip file from doc which is 128 MB. Extracted the file in C:\src\flutter. Set up the path in environmental variable which is  C:\src\flutter\bin and also set up git path in system variable. After this I downloaded plugins in android studio.

The problem is that
when I type git in CMD it works fine but when I type flutter doctor it shows

> The system cannot find the path specified.

and in android studio I also gave the path which is C:\src\flutter but it shows error says the SDK installation in incomplete. I want to set up flutter in my windows 10.

Comment: Can you share the entire output of `flutter doctor --v`? If path is not properly configured try running it with absolute path i.e. `C:\src\flutter\bin\flutter doctor --v`

Comment: when i write flutter doctor --v it says

Comment: Error: PowerShell executable not found. Either pwsh.exe or PowerShell.exe must be in your PATH.
  The system cannot find the path specified.